# Fetching jobs from oDesk

Tags: rest, c#-4.0, oauth, api-key, odesk

I have created a Windows C# 4.0 application that is fetching jobs from oDesk according to different parameters sent to the REST API. But the problem is it is only returning public jobs. When I login to a browser and visit the same URL it is returning all the jobs in browser(and not in my application) that are available to oDesk user(not private jobs) and also public jobs. I am fetching data in JSON format(but for confirming the data i am using xml format in browser).

For example I am using the following URL to fetch jobs but it is only returning public jobs.
https://www.odesk.com/api/profiles/v1/search/jobs.xml?page=0;100&q=store&t=Hourly&dp=1&st=Open&sort=date_posted;A

and if I login to oDesk site and visit the same URL in browser it shows public jobs and oDesk jobs.

so how can I get all the jobs? Can i get those jobs using oAuth or REST API key authentication using my api key and api secret? if possible then please give a little example of how to implement oAuth or a link.

Comment: Set the GET value st to Private? (st=Private)

Comment: @Allendar It doesn't show any private jobs it is just showing open jobs including completed, cancelled or in progress jobs.

Comment: I think you should address this to oDesk. I think they have made an error in their Database Query for building up the feed. Or maybe it's just not feature in the feed, as the feed seems publicly available for everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetched all the jobs using oAuth.

Answer (score 0):

Please, check these links [I just created a job posting. However, I do not see it when I do a job search. What happened?](https://kb.odesk.com/questions/583/I+just+created+a+job+posting.+However,+I+do+not+see+it+when+I+do+a+job+search.+What+happened?) and [How do I decide what job visibility to set when I create my job post?](https://kb.odesk.com/questions/583/I+just+created+a+job+posting.+However,+I+do+not+see+it+when+I+do+a+job+search.+What+happened?) - this will shed some light on what is Private/Public Job at oDesk.

Then start following oDesk Developer Wiki (developers.odesk.com) - check the sections developers.odesk.com/Authentication and developers.odesk.com/Examples

Note, that OAuth is certified protocol and official site provides a list of libraries ready for use (links are available in our doc)

When you sign your request and run it as authed user a response will contain all jobs.

p.s. developers.odesk.com is a link you should open in your browser, sorry I can not post more than 2 links